# Rapidjson returning reference to Document Value

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm having some trouble with the following method and I need some help trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I want to return a reference to a Value in a document. I am passing the Document from outside the function so that when I read a json file into it I don't "lose it".

```
const rapidjson::Value& CTestManager::GetOperations(rapidjson::Document& document)
{
    const Value Null(kObjectType);

    if (m_Tests.empty())
        return Null;

    if (m_current > m_Tests.size() - 1)
        return Null;

    Test& the_test = m_Tests[m_current];

    CMyFile fp(the_test.file.c_str()); // non-Windows use "r"
    if (!fp.is_open())
        return Null;

    u32 operations_count = 0;

    CFileBuffer json(fp);
    FileReadStream is(fp.native_handle(), json, json.size());

    if (document.ParseInsitu<kParseCommentsFlag>(json).HasParseError())
    {
        (...)
    }
    else
    {
        if (!document.IsObject())
        {
            (...)
        }
        else
        {
            auto tests = document.FindMember("td_tests");
            if (tests != document.MemberEnd())
            {
                for (SizeType i = 0; i < tests->value.Size(); i++)
                {
                    const Value& test = tests->value[i];

                    if (test["id"].GetInt() == the_test.id)
                    {
                        auto it = test.FindMember("operations");
                        if (it != test.MemberEnd())
                        {
                            //return it->value; is this legitimate?
                            return test["operations"];
                        }

                        return Null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Null;
}
```

Which I am calling like this:

```
Document document;
auto operations = TestManager().GetOperations(document);
```

When I inspect the value of `test["operations"]` inside the function I can see everything I would expect (debug code removed from the abode code).

When I inspect the returned value outside the function I can see that it's an array (which I expect). the member count int the array is correct as well, but when print it out, I only see garbage instead.

When I "print" the Value to a string inside the methods, I get what I expect (i.e. a well formated json), but when I do it outside all keys show up as "IIIIIIII" and values that aren't strings show up correctly.

```
    rapidjson::StringBuffer strbuf2;
    rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer2(strbuf2);
    ops->Accept(writer2);
```

As this didn't work I decided to change the method to receive a Value as a parameter and do a deep copy into it like this

```
u32 CTestManager::GetOperationsEx(rapidjson::Document& document, rapidjson::Value& operations)
{
   (...)

    if (document.ParseInsitu<kParseCommentsFlag>(json).HasParseError())
    {
        (...)
    }
    else
    {
        if (!document.IsObject())
        {
            (...)
        }
        else
        {
            auto tests = document.FindMember("tests");
            if (tests != document.MemberEnd())
            {
                for (SizeType i = 0; i < tests->value.Size(); i++)
                {
                    const Value& test = tests->value[i];

                    if (test["id"].GetInt() == the_test.id)
                    {
                        const Value& opv = test["operations"];

                        Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();
                        operations.CopyFrom(opv, allocator);    //would Swap work?
                        return operations.Size();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which I'm calling like this:

```
Document document;
Value operations(kObjectType);
u32 count = TestManager().GetOperationsEx(document, operations);
```

But... I get same thing!!!!

I know that it's going to be something silly but I can't put my hands on it!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case lies with the use of `ParseInSitu`. When any of the `GetOperations` exist the `CFileBuffer` loses scope and is cleaned up. Because the json is being parsed in-situ when the buffer to the file goes, so goes the data.